# Whats the best approach (design pattern) to access database in C#?

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio, design-patterns

I am a newber in design pattern. 
Currently I am developing a system where I have a releation DB. What would be the best approach to CRUD from my DB?
My current code looks like the follow (C# code):

I defined a inteface with commons functions to all classes.

```
namespace Model
{
    public interface ICommon
    {
        void insert();
        void update();
        void delete();
    }
}
```

The Common class (abstract one) implements ICommon interface and few orders methods and attributes.

```
namespace Model
{
    public abstract class Common : ICommon
    {
        public Guid RecId { set; get; }

        public abstract void insert();
        public abstract void update();
        public abstract void delete();
        public abstract List<Common> find();

        /// <summary>
        /// Insert or update the record
        /// </summary>
        public void save()
        {
            if (this.RecId == Guid.Empty)
            {
                this.insert();
            }
            else
            {
                this.update();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then, the proper class (UserTable class for example) extends the Common class and implements the abstracts methods and others particulars attributes.

The way that I am doing my CRUD its from StoresProcedures and SqlParameter, SqlCommand and SqlConnection. Here it is a example:

```
    class CustTableModel : Common
        {
            public string SerialNumber { set; get; }
            public string ApplicationVersion { set; get; }
            public string KernelVersion { set; get; }
            public string Name { set; get; }
            public bool Active { set; get; }

            public override void insert()
            {
                List<SqlParameter> parameters = new List<SqlParameter>();
                SqlParameter parameter;

                // SerialNumber
                parameter = new SqlParameter("@serialNumber", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int);
                parameter.Value = this.SerialNumber;
                parameters.Add(parameter);

                // ApplicationVersion
                parameter = new SqlParameter("@applicationVersion", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int);
                parameter.Value = this.ApplicationVersion;
                parameters.Add(parameter);

                // KernelVersion
                parameter = new SqlParameter("@kernelVersion", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int);
                parameter.Value = this.KernelVersion;
                parameters.Add(parameter);

                // Name
                parameter = new SqlParameter("@name", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int);
                parameter.Value = this.Name;
                parameters.Add(parameter);

                // Active
                parameter = new SqlParameter("@active", System.Data.SqlDbType.Bit);
                parameter.Value = this.Active;
                parameters.Add(parameter);

                DBConn.execute("CUSTTABLE_INSERT", parameters); // The code of DBConn is below.
}
}
```

Just to a better understanding, here it is the DBConn class:

```
public class DBConn
    {
        protected SqlConnection sqlConnection;
        protected string command { set; get; }
        protected List<SqlParameter> parameters { set; get; }

        protected void openConnection()
        {
            this.sqlConnection = new SqlConnection();
            this.sqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=JYL_SOAWS_DB;Integrated Security=True";
            this.sqlConnection.Open();
        }

        protected void closeConnection()
        {
            if (this.sqlConnection.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                this.sqlConnection.Close();
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Executa o processo no banco.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>Quantidade de registros afetados.</returns>
        protected SqlDataReader run()
        {
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
            SqlDataReader ret;

            this.openConnection();

            command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            command.Connection = this.sqlConnection;
            command.CommandText = this.command;

            if (this.parameters != null)
            {
                foreach (SqlParameter parameter in this.parameters)
                {
                    command.Parameters.Add(parameter);
                }
            }

            ret = command.ExecuteReader();

            this.closeConnection();

            return ret;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Interface da classe à outros objetos.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="commandName">Nome da store procedure a ser executada.</param>
        /// <param name="parameters">A lista com os parâmetros e valores.</param>
        /// <returns>Numero de registros afetados.</returns>
        public static SqlDataReader execute(string commandName, List<SqlParameter> parameters = null)
        {
            DBConn conn = new DBConn();

            conn.command = commandName;
            conn.parameters = parameters;

            return conn.run();
        }
    }
```

I am pretty sure that there is a better way.

Could anyone help me? Thanks is advance.

Comment: Research about "Entity Framework" - this will give you plenty to work against.

Comment: Yes, look into Entity Framework, which is probably what are you after.  Also look at the repository pattern and unit of work.

Comment: Screw EF.  Go check out Dapper.  Best pattern is to use someone else's well tested and regarded pattern.

Comment: Or LINQ-to-SQL. or many other frameworks and approaches... I believe that in current form question is too opinion-based as there are no criteria how to compare several approaches to pick one that is "the best".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the best pattern. I advise **not** using an ORM. especially EF.

```
public class MyModel 
{
    public string Id {get;set;}
    //public valuetype PropertyA {get;set;}  //other properties
}

public interface IMyModelRepository
{
    List<MyModel> GetModels();

    MyModel GetModelById(string id);

    void AddMyModel(MyModel model);
    //other ways you want to get models etc
}

public class MyModelRepositorySql : IMyModelRepository
{
    public List<MyModel> GetModels()
    {
        //SqlConnection etc etc
        while (SqlDataReader.Read())
        {
           results.Add(this.populateModel(dr));
        }
        return results;
    }

    protected MyModel populateModel(SqlDataReader dr)
    {
        //map fields to datareader
    }

    public MyModel GetModelById(string id)
    {
        //sql conn etc
        this.populateModel(dr);
    }
}
```

Here's my reasoning:

Using the repository pattern allows you to inject ways of persisting your data which doesn't require a database. This is essential for unit testing, but also you will find it very useful if you can inject a mock repository into your project for integration testing.

Although ORMs might seem easy at first and save you a lot of typing, they cause problems in the long run. You only need to search stack overflow for entity framework questions to see the kind of knots people get themselves tied in when they hit a query that runs in a sub optimal way.

In any large project you will run across a data fetch requirement which requires some optimized way of retrieving data, which will muck up your carefully designed object graph/injectable generic repository or clever cutting edge ORM.

POCO objects are good. Complex objects (objects which have other objects as properties) are a pain in the arse when you attempt to serialise them or recursively add to the databases, etc. Keep your underlying data models POCO and only group them together in services or viewmodels using LINQ.

Well done for using GUID `ids` btw! Don't listen to those fools who think they will never run out of `ints`! (store as `varchar(50)` and let the DBA sort the indexing out) the problem with any DB generated id is you have to be able to create objects without connecting to the database.

Comment: I'd be really cautious of using this, especially in production.  Imagine you have a billion rows in a DB; would you really want to load them all into memory?  You may find there are very few scenarios when you would want to load everything from a DB into memory at all.

Comment: Also, a MicroORM such as Dapper does the mapping bit for you, and pretty much nothing else.  You still have to write the sql, so I'm not sure why you wouldn't at least use that, regardless of your thoughts toward 'fat' ORMs

Comment: yeah GetAll() is normally only required for lists of categories etc

Comment: MicroORMs are fine until they go wrong and you spend hours googling some abandoned opensource ORM which seemed cool at the time. I remember having to pull a micro orm because they had sold out and added a table max between versions

Comment: frankly in my experience a little extra time spent typing it out long hand at the beginning will save you in the long run.

Comment: I would like to thanks all of you how have helped me, especially to Ewan and @JonBates. In my scenario, I need to constantly insert records into tables and only retrieve a small set of records from few tables. I might be wrong (since this is my first time doing such job) but I have decided to implement a mix of repository pattern and dapper. Until now, everything is going fine! Once again, thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 5):

You have hit upon two subtly different patterns here.

The first is the [repository pattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649690.aspx) - a way of abstracting away your business logic from your data access

The second is the [Active Record](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_record_pattern) pattern, whereby an entity is responsible for maintaining its own state in a database.

I would recommend you stay away from ActiveRecord in C# (you may or may not know about the [Inversion of Control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control) pattern right now, but it is very useful and fairly incompatible with AR).

I would suggest you look at something like [dapper.net](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net) if you are starting out (I still use it in my smaller projects).  It is a Micro-ORM which takes lots of the boilerplate away from using a database, without being opinionated or difficult to learn (I use and like EntityFramework & NHibernate, but they aren't anywhere as easy to pick up for a beginner).

Along with this, I would create a repository (a class with Create(Foo entity), Read(Guid entityId), Update(Foo entity) & Delete(Guid entityId) methods).

As an aside, be careful when using Guids as a primary key, as they can cause an interesting situation:  Since most Guid implementations (almost always) have a non-sequential layout, and data is physically ordered by primary key, such inserts with can cause a lot of disk IO as the database reorders data pages on disk to accommodate new data inserted at some arbitrary position within the table.  A good strategy for Guid generation for use as a primary key is to use a [Guid Comb](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=25862&seqNum=7) generator

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

For performing CRUD operations I would recommend Repository pattern with Entity framework.

Entity Framework is an ORM provided by microsoft. It deals with database using set of POCO Classes (Entity) to perform insert/update/delete/create operations.

To Execute queries against these entities, Language Integrated Query (LINQ) will be used. LINQ uses similar syntax of SQL and it returns database results as collection of Entities.

Here is a sample
[Repository pattern with EF](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_asp/mvc/using-the-repository-pattern-with-asp.net-mvc-and-entity-framework.htm)

Cheers!